# XCode's "Add to Repository" not appearing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, svn, xcode

I started a new project with XCode and I have set up the subversion repository. For some weird reason, in this project the "Add to repository" menu items are not working, both in the main menu and by right clicking a file. If the file is in the repository I can do all the usual things. Newly added files do not show with a question mark either. The only way for me to add files at this moment is via commandline.

Does anyone have a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting **Refresh Entire Project** from the **SCM** menu.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the project file to the repository?

Comment: your not set properly the scm configauration ,u may get the m symbol for the files u modify if u set configauration proper

Answer (score 0):

Did you get info on the project object in Xcode and set what kind of SCM you're using?